# I don't understand what is wrong in my question and why the comments are given opinion based and rude?

Tags: support, specific-question, comments, down-votes

I have a question about my The Workplace Stack Exchange post: [How to deal with the persons whose actions delays in taking decision?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115645/how-to-deal-with-the-persons-whose-actions-delays-in-taking-decision)

As soon as I posted this question, I started receiving down votes and got opinion based and rude comments. I don't understand. why? my question was not that bad or inappropriate. In other stackexchange accounts, for example in ELL and English, if anybody given a rude comments, within few hours that would get deleted. But in workplace it didn't happen. why is it?

The question reduced my reputation here. I am sure my question was not that bad to get negative votes of this size.

Can I get some clarity on whats gone wrong with my question? and why the people reacted personally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We cannot be certain why people downvoted your post, but if I had to take an educated guess, it was because **they perceived your post as a rant rather than trying to solve a problem**. Using phrases like *"ignorant people"*, *"his ... supporting reasons ... which is actually not acceptable by me"*, *"It is common character of most of the people."*, *"they don't correct their mistakes at all."* *"Always They will use this strategy and escape from their faults."* doesn't help your case.

The "rude" comments did not get deleted because either (1) nobody flagged them for deletion and/or (2) they were not rude. <s>You seem to be blaming the site for not deleting comments. **Did *you* flag the comments?**</s> – *My mistake, I didn't realize you didn't have the reputation to flag.*

I have now [edited your post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/115645/9) to focus on your actual issue.

Comment: When I hover over that comment I did not get the controls to flag. I thought I didn't get the option to flag because of my low reputation. after I post the question here somebody has flagged it and that comment was deleted.

Comment: related feature request at MSE: [Allow new users to flag comments on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311459/165773)